# How do I make an AppleScript file into a Mac App?

Tags: applescript

I have an Applescript that simply opens a Dialog Box, asks for a user input and runs a Terminal Command and spits out the answer. It works great in AppleScript Editor yet I am trying to work out how I could package this Script File along with an icon to make a Mac App for my personal use. Thoughts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Script Editor, select File > Save As and set File Format to Application. (In Mojave and later, the Save As choice in the File menu is not visible unless you hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.)

Open Bundle Contents drawer and see the applet.icns file, copy your icon to that.

See "Saving a script as an application" in Script Editor help.

Comment: +1, but +2 if I could. I've been using Applescript for years and had no idea about the icon trick. Very slick.

Comment: Under El Capitan this seems to be File->Export now.

Answer (score 8):

In El Capitan at least you can use `osacompile`, e.g:

```
osacompile -o MyScript.app MyScript.scpt
```

Comment: used in december 2021 on mac os big sur. works perfectly. using this in my toolchain that compiles typescript via javascript to applescript apps. If someone is interested, checkout my github

Answer (score 2):

to export an an application, do **File -> Export** and set the drop-down list to "*Application*"

Answer (score 1):

Open the information window for your Application `cmd+i` and drag your icon file (`icns` format) onto the top left default icon.