# Invoke Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

Is it possible to invoke a keyboard shortcut from applescript?

For example I like to run the F11 keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works from the terminal.

```
osascript -e "tell applications \"System Events\"" -e "key code 100" -e "end tell"
```

Alternatively I believe this should work.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 101
end tell
```

Googling mac osx system events key code should bring up several options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean open the applescript from keyboard shortcut? if so, then follow [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-file-into-a-mac-app) to convert the applescript into an app, then create a Service using Automator.

- [AppleScript to App](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-file-into-a-mac-app)
- [Open Apps from keyboard shortcut](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463)

Hope this helps.

Comment: For example I have "Show Desktop" set to f11 key.  I would like to invoke the f11 key for AppleScript.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer. You cannot open files with a keyboard shortcut like on Windows, but on Mac it'll open Apps. Therefore you have to convert the AppleScript to an app, then create a keyboard shortcut service. From then the keyboard shortcut should be accessible anytime.

Comment: Small typo "I would like to invoke keyboard shorcut from AppleScript" I have left a response that works.