# Custom macOS application bundle requires Rosetta even through it shouldn't

Tags: development, plist, apple-silicon

Since there is currently no [DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/) application bundle for macOS, I thought I could be the one to make it because I want to use it anyway. From just searching on the internet I made the following application bundle:

```
- DrJava.app
  - MacOS
    DrJava # this is a shell script that runs java -jar drjava.jar
    drjava.jar
  - Resources
    DrJavaIcon.png
    DrJavaSearchIcon.png
  Info.plist
```

And my `Info.plist` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>CFBundleName</key>
      <string>DrJava</string>
      <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
      <string>DrJava</string>
      <key>CFBundleIcon</key>
      <string>DrJavaIcon.png</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The issue with this is that when I try to run the app, it tells me that I need to install Rosetta to do so.

However, this is simply not true. I can run `./DrJava` and it will run perfectly fine without rosetta. My current guess is that there's a key in `Info.plist` that will indicate the architectures that are compatible with this bundle. But I haven't been able to find any such thing.

PS: Due to personal reasons, I don't want to make an Apple ID. As such I'm not trying to not install Xcode for as long as possible. I understand that this will make things more difficult, but I am committed.

Comment: Where is java when you run it in the Terminal?

Comment: When I run `which java` it tells me that it's located at `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: Can you show all of the DrJava script

Comment: Sure. It's `#! /usr/bin/env bash java -jar drjava.jar`

Comment: WHere is the bash that you use in the terminal?

Comment: `which` tells me it's at `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is having the same problem, I figured out a way to do this by letting Script Editor do it for me. My script is simply:

```
do shell script "java -jar drjava.jar"
```

I exported it this into an application automatically using script editor. It doesn't have an icon but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: See this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8300/237 for adding an icon